# Passing Argument into function

Tags: c, function, arguments

Write a C program to read a rupee amount (integer value) and break it
up into the smallest possible number of bank notes.
Assume bank notes are in the denominations 2000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20
and 10.

I am trying to pass amount into the denCAL() function and want to update it everytime the function is called but the value of amount remains same.

Please provide the solution for my problem and a better approach for the solution and also do le me know some good programming practises which are missing here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int amount, note, den;
int denCAL(amount, den){
note = amount/den;
amount -= note*den;
printf("Number of %d notes are:%d\n",     den, note);
}
int notes(){
printf("Enter the amount in rupees: ");
scanf("%d", &amount);
if(amount >= 2000){
    denCAL(amount, 2000);
}
if(amount >= 500){
    denCAL(amount, 1000);
}
if(amount >= 200){
    denCAL(amount, 500);
}
if(amount >= 100){
    denCAL(amount, 100);
}
if(amount >= 50){
    denCAL(amount, 50);
}
if(amount >= 20){
    denCAL(amount, 20);
}
if(amount >= 10){
    denCAL(amount, 10);
}
}
int main(){
 notes();
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter the amount in rupees: 30020
Number of 2000 notes are: 15
Number of 1000 notes are: 30
Number of 500 notes are: 60
Number of 100 notes are: 300
Number of 50 notes are: 600
Number of 20 notes are: 1501
Number of 10 notes are: 3002
```

Comment: *"want to update it everytime the function is called"* - multiple ways to do that, including global variables, static locals, pass-by-address, and return-updated value (as opposed to the otherwise-unused result type of `denCAL`. Any of those will solve your problem, and *every* one of those is different. I suggest learning pass-by-address (which is really just pass by value, but the value in that case is an address; just the way the language works). `[c] pass by address` on this site's search box will yield *hundreds* of potential answers to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're not updating your `amount` variable, even considering it's a global, it's because in your function `denCAL()`, by passing `amount` as a parameter, you're accessing a copy of it. Also you need to specify the type of the input parameters in your function prototype. You should change the code like this:

```
void denCAL(int den){ // amount is global, no need to pass it
note = amount/den;
amount -= note*den;
printf("Number of %d notes are:%d\n",     den, note);
}

void notes(){
    printf("Enter the amount in rupees: ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    if(amount >= 2000){
        denCAL(2000);
    }
    /* rest of code */
}
```

Another approach you could use, instead of using a global variable, is to use pointers for example. You could define `amount` inside `notes()`, and remove the global you've already declared.

```
void denCAL(int* amount, int den){ // passing amount by ADDRESS (so it gets modified)
note = (*amount)/den;
(*amount) -= note*den;
printf("Number of %d notes are:%d\n",     den, note);
}

void notes(){
    int amount;
    printf("Enter the amount in rupees: ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    if(amount >= 2000){
        denCAL(&amount, 2000);
    }
    /* rest of code */
}
```

Comment: Passing by reference and relaying in the side effects should the "last resort".  Bad example to the beginner. You also do not read warnings (which is even worse).

Answer (score 1):

```
int nominals[] = {2000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 0};

void getNominals(unsigned money, int *result)
{
    int *nm = nominals;
    while(*nm && money)
    {
        *result++ = money / *nm;
        money %= *nm++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int result[sizeof(nominals) / sizeof(nominals[0])] = {0};

    getNominals(30020, result);

    for(size_t index = 0; nominals[index]; index++)
    {
        printf("%d = %d\n", nominals[index], result[index]);
    }
}
```

But in your code you need:

add the `return` statement:

```
int denCAL(amount, den)
{
    int note = amount/den;
    amount -= note*den;
    printf("Number of %d notes are:%d\n",     den, note);
    return amount;
}
```

and then in every if change `denCAL(amount, ...);` to
`amount = denCAL(amount, ...);`